# What is the keyboard shortcut for method suggestions in Eclipse on Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse on Windows can I press `myObject.`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to get a list of all methods for the object. But on Mac OS X this doesn't seem to work. I have tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> but nothing seems to work.

What is the keyboard shortcut for method suggestions in Eclipse on Mac OS X?

Comment: For any googlers that landed on this page whilst searching for xcode's equivalent: press the Esc key.

Comment: use [CMD + Shift + L]  to watch all list.  [ CNTRL + . ]  - is Auto complete

Answer (score 61, accepted):

By default I believe it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. You can check by going to Preferences > General > Keys and filtering for 'content assist'.

If it's not working, you may have a binding from OS X or another application overriding it. If a window with a blank list is popping up, you may need to adjust which suggestions are shown by default in Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced. You can continue pressing the binding to cycle through the different types of suggestions.

Comment: CTRL+SPACE opens Spotlight on Mac OS X. "Content Assist" seem to be binded to `^` and a strange letter that I don't understand what it is.

Comment: Command+Space is the default key binding for Spotlight in OS X. You can always rebind both Spotlight and Content Assist in Eclipse to whatever you like.

Comment: "Content Assist" is binded to `⌃␣` - what does that mean?

Comment: hmm, no clue what that key is. I'd just rebind Spotlight to Command+Space (System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Spotlight) and rebind Content Assist in Eclipse to Ctrl+Space so you're consistent with your Windows development environment.

Comment: `⌃␣` meant CTRL+SPACE - Now I have binded "Content Assist" to SHIFT+SPACE instead and it works perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Good suggestion. I have bound Spotlight to CMD+SPACE now so I can have Content Assist on CTRL+SPACE. Thanks, this was helpful.

Comment: ctl-space works for me to bring up the content assist (cmd-space is Spotlight as others say here)

Comment: In MacOS Sierra, CRTL-SPACE is the default for switching input types. Turn this shortcut off in the keyboard preferences and CTRL-SPACE in eclipse will start working

Comment: Same problem with Mac OS Ventura (13.5.2): ^ + Space (CTRL + SPACE) was setted to change Input Source. To disable: System preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Short Cuts > Input Sources

Answer (score 24):

For OSX Mavericks/Yosemite and later/earlier versions.

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is mapped to Spotlight, therefore if you want to use this shortcut in Eclipse you'll need to unmap it:

1. Go to <kbd></kbd> -> <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> -> <kbd>Keyboard</kbd>.
2. Click the <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> tab.
3. Select **Spotlight** in the left pane (see screenshot below).
4. Untick **Show Spotlight Search field** next to the shortcut combination <kbd>^Space</kbd> as shown in the screenshot below.

NOTE: obviously, you can just remap the Spotlight hot key to something else, in case you want to have a shortcut for it, e.g. I remapped it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Keep in mind, you can always bring up the Spotlight search field by clicking it's icon ( ) in the MacOS menu bar.

[image: Now Ctr+Space will work in Eclipse]

Now <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should work in Eclipse as expected.

Answer (score 12):

Try the keys control + command + period (.)

Comment: You made my day 

Answer (score 7):

Finally! I found how to get the keyboard shortcut for code completion working in Eclipse on Mac OS X. At work, on Linux, I use CTRL-SPACE all the time in Eclipse. Unfortunately that did not work on my MacBook: CMD-SPACE triggers the spotlight search widget and CTRL-SPACE is tied to the Quicksilver launcher in my case.[image]
And there was much frustration.
First: don't say "code completion", but "content assist" in Eclipse. To bring even more confusion, there is also the "word completion" tool in the edit menu, but that's not what you normally want (it's just limited to completing a variable name without much context sensitivity). "Content assist" offers you the usual suggestions you expect from a completion tool (function names, variables, methods, properties, modules, ...).
Once I got this, it I just had to edit the keyboard shortcut for "content assist" to something that was still available (I chose ALT-SPACE).

Answer (score 4):

I think it is <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> , but i haven't worked with eclipse for a while...

Comment: No, that was a different popup, but good to know, thanks. I also tried Cmd+2, 3 and 4.

Comment: oh... sorry, i haven't installed eclipse on this machine and so I couldn't test it. hopefully someone else knows the shortcut :/

Answer (score 4):

Think its  <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.

In my installation the equivalent to the auto suggest is unbound, but you can attach a binding in Preferences>General>Keys.  The Command is called 'Content Assist (type: Java Proposals)'.

Comment: +1 Ah, that answers my question but it wasn't exactly the one I was thinking of. I would like to get the same suggestion-popup that comes up automatically after typing `myObject.` E.g after it has been shown I can press ESC to make the suggestions disappear, I would like to be able to show the same again as I can do with CTRL+SPACE on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

For OSX Big Sur and possibly later/earlier versions:

1. Go to <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Keyboard</kbd>.
2. Click the <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> tab.
3. Select **Input Sources** in the left pane (see screenshot below).
4. Untick **Select the previous input source** next to the shortcut combination <kbd>^Space</kbd> as shown in the screenshot below.

NOTE: obviously, you can just remap the **Select the previous input source** hot key to something else, in case you want to have a shortcut for it, e.g. You can remap it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

[image: Now Ctr+Space will work in Eclipse]

Now <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> should work in Eclipse as expected.

Comment: it worked well for me MacOS Big Sur 11.6

Answer (score 2):

In Lion, `CTRL+SPACE` is mapped to "Select Previous Input Source" in the "Language & Text, tab Input Sources" pref pane.

You can release this mapping by (here's the tricky part):

1. temporarily enabling an extra language
2. going to "Keyboard Shortcuts" pref pane, "Keyboard & Text Input" group, and modifying/removing the `^SPACE` from the "Select Previous Input Source" function.
3. you can now remove the temporary language input that you added in step 1.

`^SPACE` now starts emitting a system event and you can map it in applications.

Comment: This solved the problem for me on MacOS Sierra - thank you. However I was able to deselect the `^Space` binding for "Select the previous input source" by simply opening the Input Sources group in Keyboard > Shortcuts. Once I did this, when I reopened System Preferences, the Input Sources group was no longer shown. I only have one input source defined.

Answer (score 1):

you can find Word Completion under edit.(ie.Edit> Word Completion)
And hence its ctr+.

Answer (score 1):

Mac Os version: 11.01 Big sur

In your Eclipse or STS open preferences. Mac shortcut: cmd + < key

[image]

- General -> preferences -> keys -> scheme == Emacs
- General -> preferences -> keys -> content Assist -> Binding == tab (see below in image for Binding dropdown, you can change here to tab)
- now go to eclipse and use tab instead of cmd+space, you will the same result of cmd+space in windows by using tab in mac

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways you can resolve this problem.

1.**Stopping default Mac OS 'Spotlight' approach**:

```
   Go to System Preferences -> Keyboard.

   Click the Shortcuts tab.

   Select Spotlight in the left pane (see screenshot below).

   UnSelect Show Spotlight Search field next to the shortcut
   combination ^Space as shown in the screenshot below  or Change it to
your preferred shortcut.
```

2.**Modifying the Eclipse 'Content Assist' *(actual name for code/method suggestion feature)* shortcut keys**

```
    You can change shortcut key in Eclipse by going to 

    Preferences > General > Keys and filtering for 'content assist'.

    Change/Update the Shortcut key to your preferred one. (I preferred Alt+Space)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my macOS High Sierra (ver.10.13.6) default `control + space` combination seems to work for Eclipse, no change is necessary:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use Fn + command + space or option + Esc

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific set of proposals that were not enabled by default in my Eclipse installation on MacOS

[image]
[Eclipse >> Preferences >> Java >> Editor >> Content Assist >> Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuJbp.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 7, I was able to solve my problem by viewing all the global keyboard shortcuts that are bound from Windows Hotkey Explorer which showed me that I was using CTRL+Space as a key bind to mute my microphone on skype. Apparently, after rebinding that shortcut, Code assist started functioning properly.