# Why sysout shortcut won't work in Eclipse on Mac?

Tags: eclipse

I have been a windows user since the beginning, just recently switched to MacOS, all the preferences settings in my Eclipse, they are all set to default with sysout option on, but when I typed sysout in eclipse, it won't automatically go into System.out.println(). I've checked several other related topics as well as most of the resources which mention 'ctrl + space' (Which worked perfectly on Windows for me).  But, when I try to use 'command + space' on my Mac it just launches Spotlight search & I have even tried resetting the commands to default in Eclipse, Please let me know how I can get my sysout working.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764623/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-method-suggestions-in-eclipse-on-mac-os-x help?

Comment: It is still Ctrl + Space on macOS

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, In my case Ctrl + Space wasn't working, but, holding fn + Ctrl + Space, worked perfectly!!

Comment: @Jelaby Yes it kinda did Help, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be simplify in images.

Try to unbind the shortcut on mac:

1- Mac Preferences of system
[image]

2- Choose Keyboard:
[image]

3- Go to Layout of keyboard and Uncheck **"ˆspace"**
[image]

You can try to change on eclipse, but if you want to use "^space" to shortcut, will be necessary unbind this on mac. By default or mac keys as shortcut to change keyboard type.

(Eu quero Ibagens!)